# The site's identity can't be verified

Tags: networking, 18.04, nautilus

Each time I try to connect by `ftps://` by Nautilus (Ubuntu Files), I receive the message below:

```
The site's identity can't be verified:  
    The certificate does not match the identity of the site.  
Certificate information:  
    Identity:[...]  
    Verified by: [...]  
    Expires: [...]  
    Fingerprint (...):[...]  
Are you really sure you would like to continue?  
    [No][Yes]
```

I receive this message each time when I try to connect.
How to compare or confirm this *Fingerprint* to get it verified and to not to get this message again?

Comment: Connect to which site? A site you locally host, or a site elsewhere?

Comment: @K7AAY I try to connect elsewhere.

Comment: Please provide the URL.